# In Rust, why doesn't &v[1..] panic when the size of vector v is one?

Tags: vector, rust, range, slice

In the [gcd example](https://github.com/ProgrammingRust/examples/blob/master/gcd/src/main.rs) in [*Programming Rust, 2nd Edition*](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/programming-rust-2nd/9781492052586/), why doesn't `&numbers[1..]` cause an out-of-bounds error in the statement

```
for m in &numbers[1..]
```

when the size of vector `numbers` is one?  Doesn't `numbers[1]` address the second element which is one element beyond the end of the vector?

For example, I expected `gcd 45` to panic, but instead it reports a greatest common divisor of 45:

```
ubuntu@development1:~/Documents/projects/rust/programming_in_rust/examples/gcd$ cargo run 45
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.00s
     Running `target/debug/gcd 45`
The greatest common divisor of [45] is 45
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cause the doc say so:

> Panics if begin does not point to the starting byte offset of a
> character (as defined by is_char_boundary), or if begin > len. [source](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/trait.SliceIndex.html#impl-SliceIndex%3Cstr%3E-1)

Since len is `1` in your case `1..` doesn't panic and return a empty slice. Equivalent of `1..1` in your case.

Comment: Does this also mean that `&v[0..0]` when `v` is empty also does not panic?

Comment: @DerekMahar "Panics if begin or end does not point to the starting byte offset of a character (as defined by is_char_boundary), if begin > end, or if end > len." https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/trait.SliceIndex.html#impl-SliceIndex%3Cstr%3E. So &v[0..0], never panic.